# tensorflow placeholder shape [None] [None,1] difference

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. I experimented a DQN algorithm with a section involving

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None],name='A')
q = tf.reduce_sum(critic_q * tf.one_hot(a,n_outputs),axis=1,keepdims=True,name='Q')#Q value for chosen action

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None],name='Y')

learning_rate = 1e-4
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y-q))#mean squared error
global_step = tf.Variable(0,trainable=False,name='global_step')
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(cost,global_step=global_step)
```

and initialized the input y with `y_batch=np.zeros(nbatch)`. The network hardly trained at all.

Then, I switched to defining y as

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,1],name='Y')
```

and initialized the input with `y_batch=np.zeros(nbatch).reshape(-1,1)`, which worked nicely.

What was happening in the first implementation?

Comment: I faced the exact same issue. It is really weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every tensor has a rank (number of dimensions) and a set of dimensions.

A placeholder with shape `[1]` is a placeholder with rank 1 and the dimension in position 0 of 1.

A placeholder with shape `[None, 1]` is a placeholder with rank 2, hence it has 2 dimensions. The first dimension (index 0) has unknown size (it will be resolved at runtime) while the second dimension (index 1) has the known size of 1.

In order to be compatible, tensors must have the same rank a dimensions.

You can read a more complete assessment about the tensors shape here: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/#tensors-the-basic

Comment: I suppose you are implying that q has a dimension [None,1] as well. What happens when you make an operation of y-q, when y has dimension [None]?

Comment: Tensorflow operations use the broadcasting semantics, that's well explained here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html (it uses the same semantics of numpy). Hence, if there's a `1` dimension, the data of one operand is duplicated and the operation is repeated